# JavaFx TalbleView Scroll Down/Up issue

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, tableview

[image]

I have a problem on JavaFx TableView with large data such as whats happened on the items on the picture.

With huge data,the TableView do crazy works when i select a row or a cell.
I repeated the Number '131004' more than once for reference only

How can i solve this problem with large data?!? i didn't find any resource for that.

EDITED
also i have the same problem when i use scroll to up/down

The class is

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author mohammad
 */
public class EditingCellNew extends TableCell<Object, Integer> {


    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCellNew() {
        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            textField.setText(getString());
            //setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            textField.selectAll();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textField.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setGraphic(textField);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());

        textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                    commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    System.out.println("table row : " + getTableRow().getIndex());
                    updateTableRow(getTableRow());
                    updateTableColumn(getTableColumn());
                    updateTableView(getTableView());
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    updateTableRow(getTableRow());
                    updateTableView(getTableView());
                    //bondTable.getItems().set(bondTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), bondTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                    System.out.println("realesed enter");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return String.valueOf(getItem()) == null ? "" : String.valueOf(getItem());
    }  
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom cell factory?

Comment: yes , i have my own custom cell factory, can you give me a formal cell factory class to handle it on my app ?!

Comment: Edit your question to include the code for your cell implementation. That is probably causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything wrong with that. You probably don't need both event handlers on the text field. You should probably move the call to `super.startEdit();` outside of the `if` statement, but I find it hard to imagine that would be the problem. I would try replacing your cell factory with the standard one (ie `myTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter());`). It won't have exactly the behavior you have coded but you can at least check if its your custom cell that is causing the problem.

Comment: Someone told me that i should use `IntegerProperty` Instead of `Integer` or `StringProperty`  Instead of `String` , is it truth ?!

Comment: It's usually better to use JavaFX properties in the model class for your table, but that is really a different issue. Your screenshots show that the cells are not updating correctly, which is usually a problem with the implementation of the cell class. Try the above; you might have to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: how can i implement this `myTableColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter());)` , no place for that

Comment: Just replace your current call to setCellFactory(...) with that code.

Comment: still i have the same problem , can u give me your email to talk more about it?